# Java classpath setting error

Tags: java, classpath

I am getting "could not find or load main class" error even though i am setting the class path correctly.

Here is my directory structure:

```
 src\org\apache\ws\axis2
```

Inside axis2 directory, i have my Client.class file.

Now, to run the Client class file, i gave the following command from src directory

```
java -cp "C:\Documents and Settings\F1QBWFA\My Documents\Downloads\temp\src\org\apache\ws\axis2" org\apache\ws\axis2\Client
```

I tried this as well:

```
java -cp "C:\Documents and Settings\F1QBWFA\My Documents\Downloads\temp\src\org\apache\ws\axis2" org.apache.ws.axis2.Client
```

And i get the same error. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
java -cp "C:\Documents and Settings\F1QBWFA\My Documents\Downloads\temp\src" org.apache.ws.axis2.Client
```

Class path should refer to the root of your package structure, not to the specific folder of the inner package. Of course I'm assuming you have `package org.apache.ws.axis2;` at the beginning of `Client.java`

Answer (score 0):

As it implies, the classpath is set to a path where you can find, well, *classes*

I think you might be having classes stored in the `bin` or the `classes` directory.

Change your command line to:

`java -cp "C:\Documents and Settings\F1QBWFA\My Documents\Downloads\temp\classes" org.apache.ws.axis2.Client`

If you have the classes alongside src, then change it to

`java -cp "C:\Documents and Settings\F1QBWFA\My Documents\Downloads\temp\src" org.apache.ws.axis2.Client`

Classpaths should only be set till the root of the package.